# Material UI button within a grid item - attempting to float right

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui

I am trying to float right the following button but unsure how to do this using material-ui:

```
         <Grid item xs={2}>
            <Button
              variant="contained" 
              color="secondary"
              disableElevation
              startIcon={(<DeleteOutlineIcon size="0.9rem"/>)}
              onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}  
            >
              Remove
            </Button>}                    
          </Grid>
```

Not sure also if I need to actually add padding-left to this button but wanted to see if there was a better and cleaner way.

I also tried `justify="flex-end"` and unfortunately didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

add a wrapping div to your button with the following class and style :

```
<Grid item xs={2}>
          <div className="my-class">
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              disableElevation
              startIcon={<AccessAlarmIcon size="0.9rem" />}
              onClick={() => {}}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
```

style.css :

```
.my-class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
<Grid      
  container
  direction="row"
  justify="flex-end"
  alignItems="center"
>
  <Button
    variant="contained" 
    color="secondary"
    disableElevation
    startIcon={(<DeleteOutlineIcon size="0.9rem"/>)}
    onClick={() => console.log("Button is clicked")}  
  >
    Remove
  </Button>                  
</Grid>
```

[Click here for Demo at CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-meadow-um5ok?file=/src/App.js:227-612)